# Tweaks / Optimisations for iOS7

Tags: ios7

I've developed an iOS6 app for a client.

He's now asking me what tweaks / optimisations will be needed for iOS7.

Given that this is a task that lots of other people will end up going through I thought it might make sense to gather some of the more important ones here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this guide based on the official iOS7 developer documentation:
[The Essential iOS 7 Developer’s Guide](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/essential-ios-7-developers-guide/)